# transforming strings in a golang struct

Tags: struct, go, aes

I've got a json file of AES encrypted secrets. The structure is:

```
{
    "username": "asdf123ASLdf3",
    "password": "elisjdvo4etQW"
}
```

And a struct to hold these values

```
type Secrets struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

It's easy to load the encrypted json values into the struct, but what I really want is a struct with the unencrypted values.

So, for each value, I'd like to run it though a function:

`aesDecrypt(key string, value string) string`

I'm happy to have this done on the first load, or to move everything over into a new struct.

I would like to avoid repeating the json keys or the field names.

What's the best way to do this?

(Also open to other ways to manage encrypted secrets in Go)

Comment: I would not recommend to bother with custom JSON decoding handler but simply create a new struct instance as `Secrets{aesDecrypt(s.Username, key), aesDecrypt(s.Password, key)}` where `s` is the struct that is loaded from JSON. Or the key idea is to make it in one "operation"?

Comment: I don't care about doing this in one operation, but I would like to do this without having to repeat the json key or the field names.

Comment: Would be great if downvoting and marking to close were accompanied by a reason. Would probably help the community improve. That said, surprising that either action were taken as this seems like a reasonable question involving programming that others might ask and find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to define a custom JSON Unmarshaler. Another is, as you mention, copy it to another struct.

1. ### Implementing the Unmarshaler interface

   The key insight is knowing that you can override `json.Unmarshal`'s
   behaviour by implementing [the Unmarshaler interface](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler). In our
   case, that means defining a function `func (ss *Secrets)
   UnmarshalJSON(bb []byte) error` that will do the AES Decryption when
   you try to unmarshal any JSON to a `Secrets`.

   ```
   package main

   import "fmt"
   import "encoding/json"

   type Secrets struct {
       Username string `json:"username"`
       Password string `json:"password"`
   }

   func main() {
       jj := []byte(`{
           "username": "asdf123ASLdf3",
           "password": "elisjdvo4etQW"
       }`)
       var ss Secrets
       json.Unmarshal(jj, &ss)
       fmt.Println(ss)
   }

   func aesDecrypt(key, value string) string {
       return fmt.Sprintf("'%s' decrypted with key '%s'", value, key)
   }

   func (ss *Secrets) UnmarshalJSON(bb []byte) error {
       var objmap map[string]*string
       err := json.Unmarshal(bb, &objmap)
       ss.Username = aesDecrypt("my key", *objmap["password"])
       ss.Password = aesDecrypt("my key", *objmap["username"])
       return err
   }
   ```

   This outputs a `Secrets` struct:

   ```
   {'elisjdvo4etQW' decrypted with key 'my key'
    'asdf123ASLdf3' decrypted with key 'my key'}
   ```

   [See it in action at the Go Playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/rhJxGIKqpI)
2. ### Copying to another struct

   You could simply make a new `Secrets` struct every time you need to
   decrypt the JSON. This could be tedious if you do it alot, or if you
   have no need for the intermediate state.

   ```
   package main

   import "fmt"
   import "encoding/json"

   type Secrets struct {
       Username string `json:"username"`
       Password string `json:"password"`
   }

   func main() {
       jj := []byte(`{
           "username": "asdf123ASLdf3",
           "password": "elisjdvo4etQW"
       }`)
       var ss Secrets
       json.Unmarshal(jj, &ss)
       decoded := Secrets{
           aesDecrypt(ss.Username, "my key"),
           aesDecrypt(ss.Password, "my key")}
       fmt.Println(decoded)
   }

   func aesDecrypt(key, value string) string {
       return fmt.Sprintf("'%s' decrypted with key '%s'", value, key)
   }
   ```

   [Check it out at Go Playground.](http://play.golang.org/p/sXyR4em4oe)

   This has the same output as above:

   ```
   {'elisjdvo4etQW' decrypted with key 'my key'
    'asdf123ASLdf3' decrypted with key 'my key'}
   ```

Obviously, you would use a different version of `aesDecrypt`, mine's
just a dummy. And, as always, you should actually be checking the
returned errors in your own code.

Comment: This seems convenient, but I think the main challenge in your example is how to be able to provide a custom key for every call to `json.Unmarshal()`. This is something that is different from the usual unmarshaling scenario, where output depends solely on JSON data input.

Comment: @tomasz: Great point. I agree completely that that's an issue. I was illustrating the `Unmarshal` code, and consider the handling of keys and actual decryption orthogonal to the question. I don't think it would be difficult to address in any "real" code. Depending on the requirements, of course.

Comment: I like the second approach because it removes the need to type out the json key name a second time. thanks!

Comment: @Ezra sorry I "unaccepted" the answer because thinking more about it - I think it's important to not have to repeat the json keys or the field names. As the number of secrets grows, this starts to be a lot of duplicated names, and more chances for errors. Open to discuss, of course. Generally I'm curious what the best way is to handle encrypted secrets in Go.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you implement `Unmarshaler` as in (1), the only code you'd need for any additional secret is (at most) `json.Unmarshal(jj, &ss)`. It's impossible to reference them less than zero times for each additional item—I'm not sure what you're looking for. Good luck finding it! Cheers,

Comment: @Ezra towards the bottom of solution (1), within `UnmarshalJSON` you have to retype the struct value name, as well as the json key, once for each field - a great place to find bugs.

Comment: @Ezra, in fact the code snippet above has exactly this kind of bug in it: `    ss.Username = aesDecrypt("my key", *objmap["password"])`. The struct value name is mismatched with the json key. 
In a few languages (e.g. Python) it would be possible to apply a transformation to all the key/value pairs in the object, without having to type out each key/value pair. I'd like to find a way to do this in Go.